# Calculating the stimulated transition cross section of the Nd+3 YAG Laser

Tags: atomic-physics, laser

I am reading through the book "Lasers" by Anthony E. Siegman. In chapter 7 it talks about the stimulated transition cross sections for the atoms $\sigma_{21}$ in the laser gain medium, which is given by the formula

$$\sigma_\text{ho}(\omega) = \frac{3^*}{2\pi}\frac{\gamma_{\text{rad}}\lambda^2}{\Delta\omega_a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+[2(\omega-\omega_a)\Delta\omega_a]^2}$$

with a maximum of $\sigma_\text{ho}^\text{max}=\frac{3^*}{2\pi}\frac{\gamma_{\text{rad}}\lambda^2}{\Delta\omega_a}$ in the homogenous case, and

$$\sigma_\text{in}(\omega) = \sqrt{\pi\ln2}\frac{3^*}{2\pi}\frac{\gamma_{\text{rad}}\lambda^2}{\Delta\omega_d}\cdot e^{-(4\ln2)\left(\frac{\omega-\omega_a}{\Delta\omega_d}\right)^2}$$

with a maximum of $\sigma_\text{in}^\text{max}=\sqrt{\pi\ln2}\frac{3^*}{2\pi}\frac{\gamma_{\text{rad}}\lambda^2}{\Delta\omega_d}$ in the inhomogeneous case, with $\Delta\omega_a$ and $\Delta\omega_d$ being the respective line widths and $\lambda$ being the transition wavelength.

$3^*$ is described as a dimensionless polarization overlap factor and is set to equal $1$ for realistic atoms with realistic line-broadening effects.

Earlier in the chapter, the number $\gamma_{\text{rad}}$ is defined as the inverse of the decay time $\tau$ for the upper energy level of the atom. So $\gamma_{\text{rad}}=1/\tau$.

I have tried to use the formula to calculate the maximal cross-section of the $\text{Nd}^{3+}\text{YAG}$ laser using numbers I saw on a PowerPoint slide during class. It gave the numbers for the transition at $\lambda=$ 1064 nanometers where the respective upper-level lifetime was $\tau =$ 230 microseconds and the line width $\Delta\nu=$ 150 GHz.

When I plug in the numbers, I obtain a cross-section of $$\sigma_\text{ho}^\text{max}\approx 8.31\cdot10^{-18}\text{cm}^2$$ and $$\sigma_\text{in}^\text{max}\approx 1.23\cdot10^{-17}\text{cm}^2.$$ But the slide from class claims the cross section equals $3\cdot10^{-19}\text{cm}^2$. In the book, Siegmann says the transition cross section $\sigma$ of $\text{Nd}^{3+}\text{YAG}$ equals $4.6\cdot10^{-19}\text{cm}^2$. So my results are off by at least a factor of ten.

I assume the values I read from the slide are correct. Did I make a wrong assumption? What causes this difference?